# rails 3.0 view helper returned string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, helper

Thanks for your time!

I'm new to Rails and get a little confused about `view helper`.

I defined a function in `helpers/application_helper.rb`.

```
def error_table()
  return %{<table>...</table>}
end
```

I called `error_table` function in `show.html.erb`.

```
<%= error_table() %>
```

but when I view this page, it give me this string `<table>...</table>`.

I view the html source code and it looks like this : `&lt;table&gt;...&lt;/table&gt;`

I want to insert this table to the html page instead of display it. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails by default HTML-Escapes all Strings that are rendered so that no XSS attacks are possible.

So in your case you have to either call `.html_safe` on the string to mark it as "safe" HTML and it won't get escaped, or pass it to the `raw()` helper that does the same but won't bark on nil objects. ([I wrote about this](http://www.tigraine.at/2012/08/23/when-to-use-raw-and-when-to-use-html_safe/) banality some time ago)

In your case I'd suggest you put that code inside the helper:

```
def error_table()
  return %{<table>...</table>}.html_safe
end
```

Or

```
def error_table()
  return raw(%{<table>...</table>})
end
```

That way you don't have to do this on every call site

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<%=raw error_table() %>
```

After Rails 3.0, <%= %> escapes HTML by default.